# Cannot Assign Symbols to Power BI Scatterchart Data Points (argument of type 'Symbol<{}>' is not assignable to paramater of type 'Primitive'')

Tags: d3.js, svg, typescript, powerbi

I'm trying to assign symbols to data points in a Power BI scatterchart, using d3. I can easily make all of them crosses by using:

```
.attr("d", d3.svg.symbol().type("cross"))
```

I thought I'd be able to build on that by using an "if" statement to assign symbols based on values within a column called "component." There are four potential component values: OA, OI, RA, and CA. I tried to make the data points related to component OA use crosses and the rest be circles. Here's what I did:

```
.attr("d", function(d) {            
   if (d.component === "OA") { return d3.svg.symbol().type("cross") }  
   else { return d3.svg.symbol().type("circle") };   
 })
```

But I'm getting the following error.

> [ts] Argument of type '(d: ScatterChartDataPoint) => Symbol<{}>' is not assignable to parameter of type '(datum: ScatterChartDataPoint, index: number, outerIndex: number) => Primitive'. Type 'Symbol<{}>' is not assignable to type 'Primitive'. Type 'Symbol<{}>' is not assignable to type 'false.

Any idea how to fix this? I need a solution that works with d3 v3.5.5. I can't use d3 v4.

Comment: If type-checking is not important for you; try `.attr("d", function(d): any { `

Comment: Thanks @echonax. I tried as you suggested and no longer received the error, but nothing displayed in my chart.

Comment: Was it displaying something before?

Comment: @echonax, When I use .attr("d", d3.svg.symbol().type("cross")) it assigns crosses to all datapoints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the `attr` like this:

```
.attr("d", d3.svg.symbol().type((d:any)=> { 
           if (d.component === "OA") { return "cross";}
           else {return "circle";} 
        })    
)
```

You want to return the type of `d3.svg.symbol` not the `"d"` attribute. So your callback is in the wrong place.

Comment: I tried it, but got this error: Property 'component' does not exist on type '{}'.

Comment: @user7346922 does your data have that field? What does it log when you console.log(d); inside the function?

Comment: Yes it does: I see 13 log lines that include component. Here is an example:
[object Object]{band: "Eudora", category: "1973", color: "#FD625E", component: "OA", POC: "Eudora Welty", project: "The Optimis...", selectionId: Object {...}, value: 1}

Comment: @user7346922 ok so does it display the things you want? I added `d:any` to ignore that error

Comment: I got it to work! I changed d.component to (d as any).component and it worked! Thank you so much for your help. I truly do appreciate it.

Comment: @user7346922 Glad you figured it out :-)

Comment: The answer provided by @echonax, with `d:any` included, solved my problem!